# NSTask subprocess stuck in _dyld_start

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask, dyld

I use *NSTask* to run my helper application. On 99% one my customer systems this works fine, but two got back to me letting me know it doesn't. One of them was nice enough to let me look into the issue per remote desktop.

I tried a lot of different *NSPipe/NSFileHandle* combination for StandardOutput/StandardError to make sure the problem is not related filling up these buffers. Example [1](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/WrappingUnixApps) and [2](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSTaskWaitUntilExit). My guess is that it is not related because it works fine on so many systems and _dyld_start is too early on in the application lifecycle to fill up StandardOutput/StandardError.

Other notes about the problem:

- Launching the helper app from the terminal works fine.
- Attaching and detaching the gdb on the stuck process and after-worth it works fine and when it finished *NSTask* picks up work after *-waitUntilExit*.
- Using *fork(2)* and *execv(3)* instead of *NSTask* is able to launch and run the helper fine.
- The parent process is sandboxed but I think previous reports where non-sandboxed on Mac OS X 10.6/10.7.

Screenshot of the process Sample from Activity Monitor:

[image: Activity Monitor]

Any clues or debugging tips to figure out why the helper is stuck in _dyld_start are welcome!

Comment: Why are you posting images of textual data? Copy and paste the textual sample report. Also, check for console log messages. And check for `DYLD_*` environment variables.

Comment: Seconding the recommendation to check the console. For `DYLD_` environment variables, assuming you're not setting them yourself, look in ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist.

Comment: Console didn't reveal anything. Will check `DYLD_` the next time I get access to the machine.

Comment: The symptom is identical to what would happen if you use `posix_spawn` to launch an application and specify the `POSIX_SPAWN_START_SUSPENDED` flag, particularly since attaching then detaching gdb unsticks things. `NSTask` doesn't use `posix_spawn` though, unless some swizzled version of it is somehow being used.

Comment: And after thinking on this a little more I can't see how `DYLD_` variables could be relevant given that the process is stopped before `dyld` has begun execution.

Comment: @bdash thx for your comments! I checked and there is no swizzling of NSTask. Any idea if I can figure out if some suspended flag was set over the debugger?

Comment: If you can provide a `sysdiagnose` while the process is in that state then it may have enough information to help work out how it got there. Otherwise we just don't have enough information to do much beyond guess at what's causing the problem.

Comment: Easiest way to run sysdiagnose: ⇧⌃⌘⌥. (shift-ctrl-cmd-opt-period).

Comment: I ask for a sysdiagnose but haven't heart back ...

Answer (score -1):

Since nobody answered, I am throwing a few ideas. Maybe one of them is the answer – only guessing – but since clues and tips are welcome, you could take a look at:

- the list of the loaded libraries in the crash dump (there may be a clue there)
- any error that would happen in the child process (after the fork). However, I see why it could be difficult to get back any post-fork error.

If I recall correctly, NSTask calls `posix_spawn(2)`. This may be a clue, since using `fork(2)` and `execv(3)` seems working, you could focus on the differences between `NSTask` and the non-blocking alternative. Clearly, something is happening at the very beginning that prevents the child from executing properly.

- Are you sure it is stuck and not crashed? As far as the user could tell, your app your app wouldn't look like it crashed. Only the child process would crash.
- As a last resort, you could try to look for any Mach exception occuring (if
  any, that would mean an error, which you wouldn't be able to
  recover anyway. But it would provide valuable clues nonetheless).
- You can tell willing custommers to send you their sysdiagnose. 
  To this goal, ask them to hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to wait a few minutes. Soon after, their finder should pop a window to reveal a file named: `sysdiagnose_timestamp_.tar.gz`. Kindly ask them to mail it to you. Mine is around 5 MB. More details on the [sysdiagnose man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sysdiagnose.1.html).

Comment: @catlan have you had the time to investigate one or more of the suggestions (especially the sysdiagnose)?

Comment: Can I use the text in your question to as on the apple mailing lists? There are some engineers from apple there that might be willing to help.

Comment: I ask my customer for a sysdiagnose but haven't heart back ... Feel free to ask in the mail-list. Please post the link to the mail-list thread here so I can follow it as well.